# Specific integral $u$ to create the same minimizaton problem

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, maxima-minima, nonlinear-optimization, interval-arithmetic

I have the problem A:

$$\min (-x_{k\{ n \}}+u*(\sum_{k=1}^{K}x_{k\{ n \}})+\sum_{k=1}^{K}y_{k\{ n \}}))$$
$$\text{where} \quad 0<x_{k\{ n \}}<l, 0<y_{k\{ n \}}<m$$

The problem is that it is better to solve the following problem B:

$$\min (u*(\sum_{k=1}^{K}x_{k\{ n \}})+\sum_{k=1}^{K}y_{k\{ n \}}))$$ where the difference is that there is not exist this term: $-x_{k\{ n \}}$.

With a good choice of constant $u$, the problems $A$ and $B$ are the same minimization problem. $u$ depends to the limits of $x_k$ and $y_k$.

How to find a good inequality of $u$ ?

Comment: $u > \frac{1}{K}$?

Comment: must have depends on l and m

Comment: $u > \frac{l - Km}{Kl}$?

Comment: i think that is is work (i need absolute value of your result), how did you come up at this proof? thanks

Comment: Analyze the largest possible value for the terms $(\sum_{k=1}^{K}x_{k{ n }})$ and $(\sum_{k=1}^{K}y_{k{ n }})$.  Found value for $u$ such that $u (\sum_{k=1}^{K}x_{k{ n }})_{max} + (\sum_{k=1}^{K}y_{k{ n }})_{max} >> -x_{k\{ n \}}$